# How can I tell if the cursor is *already* "hovered" over a dynamically placed span after an AJAX call "replaces" that span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have used $(document).on events for mouseenter and mouseleave which works as well as they say, that is to say they work when entering and leaving the span. Here's a snippet of that code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".hover_box", function() {
    $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').prop("src", function(){
        return $(this).data("src");
    });
    $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".hover_box", function() {
    $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').hide();
});
```

However, when the span "reloads" (.html replacement) after my AJAX call, if the cursor is already hovering "over" the span, it does not trigger the mouseenter event (which really doesn't surprise me to be honest).

Is there another event than I can user $(document).on to detect this state? Or some other approach I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: There used to be a jQuery method called [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) that would have helped you do what you are trying to do. I suspect that your event listeners `.on('...')` are not registered to any new elements that come after your Ajax call, and therefore won't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a global variable to remember if the cursor is over that span and then check it after the reload.

```
var inSpan=false;

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".hover_box", function() {
  inSpan=true;  
  $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').prop("src", function(){
    return $(this).data("src");
  });
  $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".hover_box", function() {
  inSpan=false;
  $(this).next('.hidden_iframe').hide();
});
```

Then, when you replace the html in your span, just check the inSpan variable and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That seems obvious now. I think I was too caught up in thinking about about DOM events.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest approaches that are the best. :) And welcome to StackOverflow! When you choose an answer that fits best, it's customary to mark the answer as "Accepted".

Comment: What I actually did was set the ID of the relevant iframe that I needed on mouseenter and I set it back to null on mouseleave and then after the ajax call, I check if it is set, and act accordingly with that specific ID. Brilliant! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After you have reloaded the HTML, you could check whether the element has the mouse pointer with the `:hover` selector (no need to keep a global variable for this), and if so, trigger the `mouseenter` event:

```
if ($(".hover_box").is(":hover")) $(".hover_box").mouseenter();
```

A simplified demo which triggers the event every 100ms when the mouse is on the `span` element:

```js
// For demo only, every 100ms trigger mouseenter if pointing to the span
setInterval(function () {
    if ($(".hover_box").is(":hover")) $(".hover_box").mouseenter(); 
}, 100);

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".hover_box", function() {
    console.log('mouseenter event triggered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hover over span below to trigger mouseover every 100 ms: <br>
<span class="hover_box">[span]</span>
```

Comment: When trying your solution on Chrome 58.0.3029.110 using Jquery 2.2.4 I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Comment: Strange, I tested this just now with jQuery 2.2.4 on Chrome 58.0.3029.110 and get no such error. I added a snippet to demo it.